# Genymotion randomly stopped working

Tags: genymotion

I had Genymotion working fine up until today, when it randomly started displaying this message

[image]

I tried to follow the other guides about setting the various IP addresses in VirtualBox, uninstall/reinstall Genymotion and the virtual device, and toggle Virtualization off and on in my bios and none of it worked. Anyone else have anything to try?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, I had to disable `Hyper-V Virtualization`:

1. Run `cmd.exe as Administrator`
2. Type `dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V` and hit enter
3. Restart the computer

Should be good to go now